# Looking to match source column to table column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to archive several files by inserting them into an archive table.  The source files contain bids for auctions and the archive will look like:

```
Auction#  product  winning bid  winning bidder  bidder1  bidder2  bidder3  bidder4  bidder5  bidder6
20        name1    $10          bidder 7        $7       $2
20        name7    $15          bidder 2                 $15               $7
20        name5      $12        bidder 1        $12      $6                $4
```

Source file looks like:

```
Auction, product, winning bid, winning bidder, bidder10, bidder2, bidder7, bidder4, bidder1
20        name1      $10        bidder 7         $5        $7       $10      $2
20        name7      $15        bidder 2         $3        $15      $10      $7
20        name5      $12        bidder 1         $6        $6       $6       $4      $12
```

The archive table will have all bidders as column names.  The source file will only have bidders that bid on that particular auction so while the archive table will for example have 50 bidder columns the number of bidder columns will vary depending on the number of bidders for that auction.  What I need to do is to insert the data from each row and when it comes to the bids, match the bid to the bidder column and insert the bid.  I am able to insert the other data but at a loss on how to insert the bids.  Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to insert directly from source file, or are the source files being imported into their own tables then migrated?  But more importantly, which DBMS?

Comment: insert into Auction_Archive (Auction#, product, Winning_Bid, Winning _bidder, bidder1,bidder2,bidder3,bidder4,bidder5,bidder6,bidder7,bidder8,bidder9,bidder10)
select Auction, product, [Winning Bid], [Winning bidder], 
from Source

Comment: @user2220670 . . . Change the source of your archive data (at least) to a more normalized form where you have one table for auctions and another for auction bidders.